# Best app layout for webpy

Tags: python, web.py

I want to use webpy to build an app, but don't want all my source code to be in one large `.py` file. However, splitting the classes (`index`, `login` etc.) across multiple files results in problems with access to `session` and `db` objects.

What is the best layout for this kind of thing?  Ideally I would want one file per page, so each file describes a single class, but how does one go about sharing `db`s and `session`s?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

im my projects I use a `utils.py` file, in there is the code for many utilities methods used across my code, so i use this module to hold the `session` object. allowing me to access the session wherever its need to.

The code stays with something like this:

```
 
import utils
class Login(object):
    def GET(self):
        if utils.session.login:
            return "OK"
        else:
            return "Please login."
```

Comment: I think this will be the best for webpy projects.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about `web.py` specific, but in my projects I define a `db.py` (or similiar module), which defines how to access db connections. From there I import e.g. a `Session()` factory, which gives me the session object(s), and do that in all modules where I need it I do:

```
from db import Session

def some_function():
    session = Session()
    some_obj = session.get(some_id)
```

In `db.py` would be the encapsulation of the database access portion of the ORM framework of your choice.